# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, classcastexception

I want to multiply a value after retrieving it from the database(realtime firebase) and assign to another variable. I tried to do it like this, but I am getting an error. Can someone please help me?

```
 private void getData(final TextView deliCha) {
        rootRef.child(appId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                double Distance = (double) dataSnapshot.child("Distance").getValue();
                double charge = Distance*100.0;
                deliCha.setText(String.valueOf(charge));
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

this the error.

```
    Process: com.example.ketomate, PID: 13156
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
        at com.example.ketomate.BillDetailsForPaymentAndDelivery$2.onDataChange(BillDetailsForPaymentAndDelivery.java:121)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: You need to use Double.parseDouble method to convert String to Double.

Comment: @Nirav I did it as you said, but it gives this error. `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6.016539 Kilometers" `

Comment: What's the data type of `DataSnapshot`?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-It is a string value. It worked when I removed "Kilometers" part.

Comment: you need to remove `Kilometers` from the value. that's what causing the issue. You may want to change the model. But, just to get this working, get the string value from DataSnapshot and replace ` Kilometers` with empty string. that'll give you "6.016539" as a string. See no extra spaces. and then you can convert the string to Double.

Comment: @Nirav Yes, it worked when I removed 'Kilometers' from the value. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"6.016539 Kilometers" string can not be converted to double because it has the word Kilometers. first you need to remove the word Kilometers before you convert to double.

```
private void getData(final TextView deliCha) {
    rootRef.child(appId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String distance = dataSnapshot.child("Distance").getValue();
            String[] separate = distance.split("Kilometers");
            double d = Double.parseDouble(separate[0]);
            double charge = d*100.0;
            deliCha.setText(String.valueOf(charge));
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, It worked after removing "Kilometers" part. Anyway I tried your method, but the word 'spilit' appears in red and shows 'Cannot resolve method 'split(java.lang.String, double)'. Thank you anyway.

Comment: ohh, my bad. i forgot to change the double to string

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Double.valueOf` method

```
double Distance = Double.valueOf (dataSnapshot.child("Distance").getValue());
```

Comment: Does not work. It suggests me to cast to double again like this. `double Distance = Double.valueOf((Double) dataSnapshot.child("Distance").getValue());` and it gives the same error.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String) is the method I am suggesting.  Maybe the value returned is not even a String?

Comment: It worked after removing "Kilometers" part. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Hmm, that was really important information which should have been in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the contents of your database, all I can conclude is that the value of a child called "Distance" is a string value, not a Double.  You can't just cast a string to a double.

The first thing to do would be to fix the way you write values into the database.  Instead of writing String values, convert them to doubles first, so that Firestore will return them to you as a double.

If you can't do that, you will have to convert the String to a double when you read it.

```
String distance = dataSnapshot.child("Distance").getValue(String.class);
double doubleDistance = Double.parseDouble(Distance);
double charge = doubleDistance * 100.0;
deliCha.setText(Double.toString(charge));
```

Comment: Yes, it is a string vaue. I tried your method, but I am getting this error. `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6.016539 Kilometers" `

Comment: You will have to strip out the "Kilometers" part . Or better yet, don't include that in the database at all and store just a double value.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked after removing "Kilometers" part.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, it's customary to upvote it, even if you don't accept it as correct.

Comment: I did, but I have no enough reputation to cast an upvote.